# Create Array after importing JSON data from AlamoFire

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire

I'm making an API call but, the response is coming back properly. This is an array of youtube links:

```
"items": [
  {
   "kind": "youtube#playlistItem",
   "etag": "\"XI7nbFXulYBIpL0ayR_gDh3eu1k/1GDmRHbln92JxGtet7SSiPs9SaY\"",
   "id": "UEw1dHZnblY0RmtqMHdpeFZ0bmNLZklqMEZuZEZmRUpYdS41NkI0NEY2RDEwNTU3Q0M2",
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2018-10-17T22:37:35.000Z",
    "channelId": "UCf-gdftRGql5XOUd_ZpVnZg",
    "title": "A Republican, Democrat, and Independent Drink Together | Strange Brew | ",
url:www.test url
}
    }
    }
    ]
```

Here is function to load Videos:

class Video: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

```
var video = [LicenseDetails]()
let recVideos = NSURL(string: RecVideos)





func loadVideos() {
Helpers.showActivityIndicator(activityIndicator, view)

APIManager.shared.recVideos { json in
        if json != nil {
            self.video = []

            print("Lookin In", json)

//            Adds all items into the array list dist then goes through them all.
            if let listDis = json["items"].array {
                print("Looking For Items", listDis)

                for item in listDis {

                    let Video = LicenseDetails(json: item)
                    self.video.append(Video)
                    print("Test: ", self.video)

                }

                Helpers.hideActivityIndicator(self.activityIndicator)

            }
            }
        }
    }
```

And I'm trying to parse the data coming in through the LicenseDetail Class

```
class LicenseDetails {

    var title: String?
    var url: String?
    var videoId: String?



    init(json: JSON) {

        self.title = json["title"].string
        self.videoId = json["resourceId"]["videoId"].string

    }
}
```

I do not understand why I cannot populate my listDis array with the data from the JSON information and then parse it with my LicenseDetail(json:json) method. Please assist.

Comment: Are you like getting an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First make sure you initialize all stored properties. And you need to cast Json data to string. I used Swift way of casting. with amofire is either as you wrote or something like this  `self.title = json["title"].stringValue`

```
struct LicenseDetails {
    var title: String
    var url: String
    var videoId: String

    init(json: JSON) {
        self.title = json["title"] as! String
        self.url = json["title"] as! String
        self.videoId = json["videoId"] as! String
    }
}
```

Next, leave ONLY the JSON fetching part to the `loadVideos()` func and move the rest to the ViewController and set an init for it like this:

```
class Video: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    var videos = [LicenseDetails]()
    required init(json: JSON) throws {
        super.init()
        let listDis = json["items"].array
        self.videos = listDist.map{LicenseDetails(json:$0)}
    }
}
```

And that's it. Hope it works.

Comment: I can't get this to work. I have moved all the other out to the view controller but, I get this error: 'self' used before 'super.init' call

Comment: Also, I think that I left out some declarations. Please take a look at my updated code.

Comment: Can you share a git isolating the problem so I can fix it myself?

Comment: I've updated my code to show exactly what it is in my git. I think the issue was you thought the variable var videos = [Video]() instead of video = [LicenseData]()

Comment: No. That is the issue.

Comment: Well change "Video" to "LicenseData" will you?

Comment: I will come back in a few hours with the corected code.